# Multiple HTTP POST Requests with updated xml template

Tags: xml, perl, csv, http-post

I want to make Multiple HTTP POST Requests. My template.xml for POST Request uploads from Input.scv data, which contains Information about devices, those should be added (names, ipaddresses).

###Input.csv (Name, IP Address)

```
LAB-1,10.26.0.1
LAB-2,10.26.0.2
LAB-3,10.26.0.3
```

###template.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:networkdevice
        xmlns:ns0="network.ers.ise.cisco.com" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns1="ers.ise.cisco.com"
        xmlns:ers="ers.ise.cisco.com"
        name="name1">
    <authenticationSettings>
        <enableKeyWrap>true</enableKeyWrap>
        <keyEncryptionKey>1234567890123456</keyEncryptionKey>
        <keyInputFormat>ASCII</keyInputFormat>
        <networkProtocol>RADIUS</networkProtocol>
        <radiusSharedSecret>aaa</radiusSharedSecret>
    </authenticationSettings>
    <coaPort>1700</coaPort>
    <NetworkDeviceIPList>
        <NetworkDeviceIP>
            <ipaddress>1.1.1.1</ipaddress>
            <mask>32</mask>
        </NetworkDeviceIP>
    </NetworkDeviceIPList>
</ns0:networkdevice>
```

I have now updated XML, which is right. I need now to add my devices to managementsystem.

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use XML::Twig;
   use LWP::UserAgent;
   use HTTP::Headers;
   use HTTP::Request;
   use File::Slurp;
   use LWP 5.64;
   use MIME::Base64;
   use IO::Socket::SSL;

  my $xml = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'template.xml' );
  $xml ->set_pretty_print('indented_a');

  open ( my $input, '<', 'input.csv' ) or die $!;

  while ( <$input> ) {
  chomp;
  my ( $name, $ip ) = split /,/;
  $xml -> root -> set_att('name', $name );
  $xml -> get_xpath('//ipaddress',0) -> set_text($ip);

  $xml -> sprint;

  #Create a user agent object
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts=> {
  SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE(),
  verify_hostname => 0,
  }
  );
  my $uri='https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice';
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $uri, 
  [Accept=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml',
  Content_Type=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml; 
  charset=utf-8'], $xml);
  
  $req->content($xml);
  $req->authorization_basic("user", "user");

  #Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
  my $res = $ua->request($req);
  #Check the outcome of the response
  if ($res->is_success) {
    print $res->status_line, "n";
       } else {
         print $res->status_line, "n";
      }

}
```

After script running I have this error (for each try):

`500 Not a SCALAR referencen`

Comment: What is this stray bit of code doing -> `Content=>[$xml];`

Comment: Without this line I have the same error :D
I just tried to represent my data in hash

Comment: Of course you would still get the error - that line wasn't inside the call to `new`, so wasn't doing anything :)

Comment: Also,  you should move `$ua` creation outside of the loop as it is constant for all requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a string to the request rather than an object, so you have to convert `$xml` into a string

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $uri, 
[Accept=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml',
Content_Type=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml; 
charset=utf-8'], $xml->sprint);
```

Comment: It's making multiple requests? You should change this line `$xml -> sprint;` to `$xml -> print;` as currently it does nothing, but you by changing it, it'll print out the generated XML for each line.

Comment: with `$xml -> sprint` it does multiple requests, it works

Comment: I meant line 23 before the comment "Create a user agent object". Not anything in the actual request part of the code. It does nothing except waste CPU cycles as currently written.